Arrayformula Serial Number by Groups
I have :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12bz_CWHE1xc7JDvwCVLUCkxSgFmgZQy4-m7OMZ-kAjU/edit?usp=sharing
The expected results are as in column D
and have been successful with the drag down formula :
=IF(B2="";;MATCH(B2;UNIQUE(FILTER(B$2:B;A$2:A=A2));0))
But I need an arrayformula to complete it, in order not to manually drag down every time to add a row between them.
I thank you in advance for your help


Converting your drag-down formula to array-style:
=map(B3:B,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,xmatch(Σ,unique(filter(B:B,A:A=offset(Σ,,-1)))))))



Thanks a lot @rockinfreakshow, it work even for additional levels
